# html2canvas with a sticky header causing image problems

Tags: javascript, table, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas in my Salesforce app to export a table as an pdf, but I am having problems with the header becoming misplaced when I scroll. The table is on its own div on the page and I tried having the code make it scroll to the top when I fire html2canvas but I can't do that either..

JS file

```
 exportToPDF(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    try {
        var pdfImageToDownload = this.template.querySelector('.region-table');
        const postfix = this.getPostFixFileName();
        var downloadFileName = `${this.tableName}_${postfix}`;
        var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        var scroll = document.querySelector('.table-area')?.then(
        scroll.scroll({
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          }));
   
            html2canvas($(pdfImageToDownload), {
            scrollY: -window.scrollY,
            allowTaint: true,
            logging: false,
            useCORS: true,
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                const imgProps = doc.getImageProperties(imgData);
                const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
                doc.save(`${downloadFileName}.pdf`);
            }
        }
        )

       
    } catch (err) {
        trace(this.componentType + ' ' + err);
    }
}
```

HTML file - just showing the basic set up

```
<template><lightning-card><article><div class="table-area"> <table class="region-table"> </table> </div></article></lightning-card></template>
```

CSS file

```
.table-area {
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

Edit: I guess main question is how can I scroll to the top in the component in Salesforce as a quick fix for the html2canvas issue? If I don't have the question mark or if i don't do if(scroll){scroll.scroll)} then it shows "TypeError: Cannot Read Property of Null."

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify how this is related to Salesforce.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am using this in the salesforce app but every possible solutions i found online isn't working so I wasn't sure if it is a salesforce issue..

Answer (score 0):

were you able to get html2Canvas load and save a file period?  Even if it isn't with the correct location?  For myself and others we all seem to get

"Uncaught (in promise) Unable to find element in cloned iframe". and would love to know how you got around this, I figure the setting you set did this but its still happening.